# Socket rooms not working like they are suppose to

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I have a piece of code setup but sockets are being sent out to the wrong person, and I have no idea why. When I update someones status the status of the other user gets updated.

**Basic Code**

```
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('login', function(token) {
    /* Database call for user */
    socket.to(user.id);
  }
});

var getSocket(userId){
  var socketFromRoom = io.sockets.in(userId);
  return socketFromRoom;
}
```

I recently switched from just storing users in an object to the above, this way I could easily send data to multiple tabs when an user has logged i. Whenever I use `getSocket(1).emit({...}` data gets emitted to the wrong person, which is very worrying.

Comment: `io.sockets.in(someRoomName).emit()` sends to all sockets in that room.  If that message is going to the wrong person, then you either have the wrong room name or you are putting the wrong sockets into that room.  Nothing more we can say without seeing a bunch more code that manages all that.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#) and the docs of [rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#).

Use join/leave to work with rooms:

```
socket.join(roomId);
socket.leave(roomId);
```

I think you should change:

```
socket.to(user.id);
```

To:

```
socket.join(user.id);
```

From the docs:

```
// sending to all clients in 'game' room, including sender
io.in('game').emit('big-announcement', 'the game will start soon');
```

To send to individual socket, use:

```
socket.to(<socketid>).emit('hey', 'I just met you');
```